# Export plot data in Mathematica

Tags: export, data

How can I export data, which is plotted using something such as:

```
Plot[Γ[x]/(1.6*10^(-19)), {x, 0.1, 1.2}]
```

into a .txt file in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Are you looking to export the plot as image or do you really want the point data created by the `Plot` function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the data using `Table`, as

```
Table[{x, Γ[x]/(1.6*10^(-19))}, {x, 0.1, 1.2, 0.01}]
```

and export the result using `Export["output.txt", result, "Table"]`

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
Export["output.txt", Cases[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0.1, 1.2}], Line@x__ -> x, Infinity], "Table"]
```